# is it possible to use numpy.take to pick a list of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to take some indices from the elements of a numpy.array. This is what I've got so far:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(range(20))
a.shape=4,5
#~ [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
#~ [ 5  6  7  8  9]
#~ [10 11 12 13 14]
#~ [15 16 17 18 19]]

idxs = np.array([(4,0),(3,1),(2,1),(0,3)])
ret = a.take(idxs,1).diagonal().transpose()
print ret

#~ [[  4.   0.]
#~ [  8.   6.]
#~ [ 12.  11.]
#~ [ 15.  18.]]
```

Is is possible to get this result in a simpler (or faster) way?

Comment: Your `idxs` would work on transposed `a` only. There is no `a[4,0]`.

Comment: I didn't explain myself so well, sorry. The (4,0) that you see means to take element 4 and element 0 from the first row. Then take element 3 and 1 from second row, etc. The result I show is correct, I am not satisfied by the method.

Comment: Also just as a general note, to create `a`, you should use something like `a=np.arange(20).reshape((4,5))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create an array for axis 0 index:

```
a[np.arange(4)[:,None], idxs]
```